# Trying to identify a cartoon about a tribe from a secluded island defending a whale

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

It was about this whale that was special, and this tribe, I think, that lived on a secluded island and had to defend the island from intruders who were trying to steal the whale. There was something else off of the island.

I remember it being in English so I'm hoping it was American or Canadian because I can't find it anywhere. The main character was a girl, I think.

Comment: Is there anything about this which makes it Science Fiction or Fantasy?

Comment: Maybe let it stay open but move it here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Could it be The Marvelous Adventures of Flapjack? [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marvelous_Misadventures_of_Flapjack)

> It stars creator Thurop Van Orman as the voice of Flapjack, a naïve young boy who was raised by a whale named Bubbie and is mentored by a salty sea pirate called Captain K'nuckles. Together the trio spend their days in Stormalong Harbor, where most of the show takes place, whilst on the search for the elusive Candied Island.

[image: Flapjack]